# How to copy file object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am opening a file in python using with command as given below. Then I am copying the object to w.

```
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\")

with open(r"abc.040", 'r+') as k:
    w = k

for a in w:
    print(a)
```

But when I try to iterate w object through for loop, I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/w.py", line 8, in <module>
    for a in w:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

How to copy a file instance

Comment: The error itself is self explanatory.

Comment: Is the indentation the same as you're showing here?

Comment: @ a_python_user You are right, but I want to make a copy and use that copy. Something like deepcopy.

Comment: @ Sayse yes indentation same as I have shown here

Comment: Unlike some other languages Python creates references by `=` and no copies. So you are still using the same object just under a new name.

Comment: When you open a file in a `with` block, the file gets automatically closed when you exit the block. `k` (and `w`, they are just two names for the same file object) is closed when you reach the `for` loop.

Comment: `w = k` is not a copy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga then how to copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readlines`

**Ex:**

```
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users")
with open(r"abc.040", 'r+') as k:
    w = k.readlines()

for a in w:
    print(a)
```

Comment: Is it not possible to copy the object and use it. Something like deepcopy

Comment: file content is copied to `w` using 'readlines' for you to reuse.